# String format padding with \0?

Tags: c++, boost

Seems that both sprintf and Boost.Format use space to pad:

```
boost::format fmt("%012s");
fmt % "123";
std::string s3 = fmt.str();
```

Is there a way to pad with '\0'?

Comment: Can I ask why you would like to pad with `\0`?

Comment: It is required by the network protocol.

Comment: I don't think that there is any function to this. You should write your own function for doing that.

Comment: There are many existing example of padding a string if you just search a little. And it's not hard to do either if you want to give it a go yourself.

Comment: If you're encoding for a specific network protocol you should do this in a more low-level manner than trying to pad using string functions.

Comment: I'm wondering a little bit. IMHO, formatting with `printf()` family is dedicated for text output (I hardly deny to write "human readable" output.) Your network protocol may be based on ASCII text or may be binary - you didn't write. However, why should be `'\0'` (`0x00u`) part of ASCII text as it is usually the end of string marker? Hard to belief...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is tagged as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Though, OP mentions *sprintf and Boost.Format* but not the output stream operators of C++. This is a bit surprising for me.

Although I'm in doubt whether this is really required/needed in OP's network protocol – using C++ output operators and `iomanip` it becomes rather easy.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('\0') << 123;
  const std::string dump = out.str();
  std::cout << "length of dump: " << dump.size() << '\n';
  for (char c : dump) {
    std::cout << ' ' << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
      << std::setbase(16) << (unsigned)(unsigned char)c;
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
length of dump: 10
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 32 33
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/606b60636485aa3f)</kbd>

As `'\0'` is a non-printable character, I did the output into a `std::ostringstream`, retrieving the output as `std::string` and print the individual characters as hex-codes:

- `std::setw(10)` caused right-alignment to 10 characters.
- `std::setfill('\0')` caused padding with `'\0'` bytes.
- `31 32 33` are the ASCII codes for `123` the `int` constant given for output.

---

I missed the fact that OP wants to format a string (not a number). However, it works for strings as well:

Formatting:

```
out << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('\0') << "abc";
```

Output:

```
length of dump: 10
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 61 62 63
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b96de0e033e393d)</kbd>

Comment: @user1633272 I realized that you want to format string (instead of an `int`). However, it works the same way. (Answer extended.)

Comment: Output stream could do this, it is just not that flexible for different align types for a single format.

Comment: @user1633272 IMHO, C++ stream formatting with I/O manipulators is at least as flexible as the `printf()` family but probably more. (`std::setfill()` is an example. I believe there is nothing like this in `printf()` but only the choice between `' '` and `'0'` as fill character.)